# Dream of.. versus Dream with

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

Which of the following sentences is more correct to say?

> 1. "Do you dream of a perfect smile?"
> 2. "Do you dream with a perfect smile?"

Comment: If you mean dreaming *about* a perfect smile, or that a perfect smile is the subject of your dream, then it is **of**.  But I think I understand your question.  Si significas *with* como "... soñaba *con* los héroes de la Ilíada...", entonces deseas **of**.

Comment: @stangdon "Si (tú) significas (algo) como" sounds strange in Spanish. A person do not apply an action over something to force a meaning. La frase más correcta sería "El equivalente en inglés de "soñar con" es "dream of" ;-P

Comment: Another example of that equivalency is the traslation applied to the famous "Do androids dream of electric sheep?" by Philip K.Dick. In Spanish "¿Sueñan los androides con ovejas eléctricas?". "Blade Runner" para los amigos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *correct way* because these have different meaning.

> Do you dream of a perfect smile?

-> The subject of your dream is the perfect smile; you are dreaming *about* the smile.

> Do you dream with a perfect smile?

-> There is a perfect smile on your face.

Still, dreaming *of* a perfect smile can result in dreaming *with* a perfect smile.